# Excel VBA array length exceed a line and throwing error

Tags: excel

I have declared following variable in excel VBA

```
>  Dim arrayCollabName as variant 
>  arrayCollabName = Array("Name1","Name2", ....."Name62")
```

But the Names inside the array are exceeding 1 line in VBA sheet and throwing error

Any suggestion on how to do this without error

Comment: Do you mean the VBA editor has tried wrapping some of the names in the array onto the next line of code?  If so, try adding an underscore to the end of the previous lines.  That's the line-continuation character in VBA...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arrayCollabName = Array("Name1","Name2",..., _
"Name N","Name n+1",...,_
...)
```

Underscore is the trick to seperate lines.